# How to reject email falsely claiming to be from a local address in Postfix?

Tags: configuration, postfix

Let's suppose I run the mail server for `example.com` and the server is running Postfix on Ubuntu. There are two registered users, `alice` and `bob`.

Postfix receives an email from `badhost.com` like so:

```
To: alice@example.com
From: bob@example.com
...
```

Using the default configuration, Postfix happily accepts the email and delivers it to `alice`'s mailbox. The email, of course, isn't actually from `bob`.

Is there a way to tell Postfix that it should not be accepting email falsely claiming to be from local address? In other words, `alice` should be assured that whenever she receives an email from `example.com`, it is authentic.

I wondered about forcing SPF but a lot of legitimate email comes from domains that don't have SPF set up.

Comment: Look at  `DKIM`.  You can't force the others to sign their messages but you can sign yours (doubling the processing and bandwidth requirements).

Comment: This *might* be better asked on https://security.stackexchange.com/ despite it is Linux - related.

Comment: Possibly related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294300/128583 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276529/128583